#  Using Aforge.NET under wince

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-mobile, windows-ce, aforge

How to use [Aforge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com) under wince?
When I build my program that uses Aforge library for compact framework I get this error:

> The type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Answer (score 1):

You must compile the AForge code under the Compact Framework, if it's not already done.  Compact Framework assemblies cannot reference desktop assemblies (which the public key 'b03f5f7f11d50a3a' indicates that the AForge stuff you're attempting to reference uses).

Comment: I tried to compile Aforge for CF but it faild because it uses some .NET features that is not implemented on Comapct Framework.

Comment: Then you're going to have to find an alternative.